# Function to compute partial derivatives of function with arbitrary many variables

Tags: scala, functional-programming, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a function in `Scala` that will compute the partial derivative of a function with arbitrary many variables.  For example

**One Variable(regular derivative):**

```
def partialDerivative(f: Double => Double)(x: Double) = { (f(x+0.001)-f(x))/0.001 }
```

**Two Variables:**

```
def partialDerivative(c: Char, f: (Double, Double) => Double)(x: Double)(y: Double) = {
  if (c == 'x') (f(x+0.0001, y)-f(x, y))/0.0001
  else if (c == 'y') (f(x, y+0.0001)-f(x, y))/0.0001
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to write `partialDerivative` where the number of variables in `f` do not need to be known in advance.

I read some blog posts about `varargs` but can't seem to come up with the correct signature.
Here is what I tried.

```
def func(f: (Double*) => Double)(n: Double*)
```

but this doesn't seem to be correct.  Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

`Double*` means `f` accepts an arbitrary `Seq` of `Double`s, which is not correct.

The only way I can think of to write something like this is using shapeless `Sized`. You will need more implicits than this, and possibly some type-level equality implicits as well; type-level programming in scala is quite complex and I don't have the time to debug this properly, but it should give you some idea:

```
def partialDerivative[N <: Nat, I <: Nat](f: Sized[Seq[Double], N] => Double)(i: I, xs: Sized[Seq[Double], N])(implicit diff: Diff[I, N]) = {
  val (before, atAndAfter) = xs.splitAt(i)
  val incrementedAtAndAfter = (atAndAfter.head + 0.0001) +: atAndAfter.tail
  val incremented = before ++ incrementedAtAndAfter
  (f(incremeted) - f(xs)) / 0.0001
}
```